Problem with the entry widget using Tkinter Python
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1600x800+0+0")
root.title("my notepad")

Tops = Frame(root, width=1650, height=50, bg="light green", relief=SUNKEN)
Tops.pack(side=TOP)
note = StringVar()

Bottom = Frame(root, width=1600, height=655, bg="light blue", relief=SUNKEN)
Bottom.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=True)  # Adjusted pack parameters

txtstotal = Entry(Bottom, font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), textvariable=note, bd=10, insertwidth=4,
                  bg="light blue", justify="left")
txtstotal.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = True)

root.mainloop()

Here in the line txtstotal.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = True), I made the entry widget to the size of the full screen, but the problem is because of doing that, the cursor is now at the center of the screen, which I don't want. I want a big entry widget, but the cursor starts from the top like normal.
What should I do?

The cursor cannot start from top when using Entry widget.

You should use the Text widget as explained at Tkinter Entry.

The entry widget can only accept a single line of text. Is that really what you want? Or are you looking for a multiline widget? It sounds like you need a Text widget.

The Entry widget is a single line widget. So If your goal is to have only a single line widget,  But the letters to be as big as the height of the widget, increase the font-size accordingly.
txtstotal = Entry(Bottom, font=('arial', 320, 'bold'), bd=10, insertwidth=4, bg="light blue", justify = 'left')

Or if you want the widgets to accept multiple lines. use Text widget. For Text widget, you can't assign a textvariable. Remove justify attribute.
txtstotal = Text(Bottom, font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), bd=10, insertwidth=4, bg="light blue")

The user input in the text widget can be accessed using txtstotal.get("1.0","end-1c")
